# Wine does not launch. How do I install it properly on Kubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: windows, kubuntu, wine

I have been using Kubuntu 10.04 LTS until last month and used to run a Windows programme (accounting) with Wine with great success.  I do not remember having any problem since the beginning (many years).

Unable to make a clean upgrade of the operating system, I had to make a fresh install of Kubuntu 16.04 LTS. I lost most of my settings, links, tweaks, etc. during the re-installation.

I tried to install Wine, but it constantly asks to install files that I cannot seem to find (perharps obsolete files?).

```
libgnutls-deb0-28 | libgnutls26 libgnutls-deb0-28:i386 | libgnutls26:i386
```

Wine does not launch properly and I cannot use my Windows programme (which I purchased).

I am not much familiar with Linux coding, but do use coding whenever necessary, although I must admit I am not every time sure what I am doing.

I have created a thread on Winehq forum.  The moderator finally said that I should get help from Ubuntu forums to get those three files.

Is there anybody who could shed some light on Wine installation and help me make it properly work?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Those packages are available in the repositories, though in newer versions

```
sudo apt install libgnutls-dev libgnutls-dev:i386
```

Will install the packages you need.

Comment: I tried but it seems that there are dependencies problems   that I do not understand:

Shirin:~$ sudo apt install libgnutls-dev libgnutls-dev:i386

Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 libgnutls-dev:i386 : Dépend: nettle-dev:i386 mais ne sera pas installé
                      Dépend: libidn11-dev:i386 (>= 1.31) mais ne sera pas installé
E: Impossible de corriger les problèmes, des paquets défectueux sont en mode « garder en l'état ».
Shirin:~$